# is it risky to rely on tenants to pay for mortage?

Tags: mortgage, real-estate

Say I buy a duplex for $800k which has a monthly mortgage of around $4500.  My take home say is only $4500 a month.  I know I can rent out one side of the duplex for $2500 a month so I would be able to pay it assuming I rent it out since there is only $2000 left on the mortgage.

In this scenario would it be risky to buy this house?  Some cons would be if I lose my job somehow or can't find a tenant then I assume the home would foreclose?  But that is very unlikely.

Edit changed some numbers

Comment: Is it risky? yes, it is risky. Of course it's risky, but you're saying that the risk materializing is unlikely (why?)

Answer (score 7):

Mortgage lenders will evaluate your debt to income ratio (DTI), conventional lenders will not exceed 50% back-end DTI (DTI including new mortgage). They might consider up to 75% of the potential rental income towards qualifying for the loan. Even with the potential rent you'd be ~70% DTI from just the mortgage.

Even if you could qualify for a loan, unless you had very healthy savings you weren't using for a down payment you'd be running too thin, you wouldn't be able to weather a major repair, vacancy, or job loss.

Comment: "They might consider up to 75% of the potential rental income towards qualifying for the loan" - I believe this is to cover the expectation that the unit is only occupied ~75% of the time on average, which you mention further down in your answer when you talk about vacancy, but I think this answer would be improved by clarifying that upfront.

Answer (score 4):

You can't guarantee that the unit will always be occupied. You can't guarantee that the market will always let you charge the rent you want. You are essentially buying a home and starting a business simultaneously, and you need to run *all* the numbers to establish whether that's viable.

Personally: If you can't afford the mortgage without the rental income, you will be dangerously overextended. If you *can* afford it, this may be worth considering.

I looked at the option of buying a duplex, and decided that the hassle of being a landlord (plus losing the sound isolation that a private house gives you) made it a bad idea, even though I am handy enough to do much of the maintenance myself. Your mileage may vary. Don't guess; run ALL the numbers and consider the non-financial costs before deciding you want to do this.

Comment: Yes but the thing is if I buy single family home it will probably be 70% to 80% of the cost of the duplex but I don't get the rental income.  option would be to save more of the down payment so mortage is 500k ish

Comment: @Bigbob23 do you have a plan on how you'll make your mortgage payments if a tenant trashes the place and you have to have it off the rental market for 3  months while you rehab it? This is a near worst-case scenario, but it does happen and you need to be prepared for it.

Comment: Or the housing market crashing, no-one wants to rent at this price anymore (or at all) and you have a long vacancy? Even with the rental income you seem to be planning living paycheck to paycheck.

Comment: Or a major repair (I'm spending $40k this week). Beware having _all_ your wealth tied up in the house.

Answer (score 2):

Anything related to investing is risky in some way, but that's the hurdle that makes it possible to gain a reward. Controlling risk is a skill in any kind of investing. Not everyone is willing to, or desires to, master that skill, or other investing and management skills.

When you look at the downside, look at more than the mortgage. You have other costs, including insurance, property tax, and maintenance. Failure to account for these is a management error; it often presents as a lack of maintenance in the property, and poor satisfaction, or even poor conditions, for tenants. Something to avoid, obviously.

So first: can you rent out the other side for $2,500 per month, and will the $500 over the mortgage pay for insurance, property tax, and maintenance. That depends! But it already sounds tight. Unless this is a new property, or a newly remodeled property, are you sure that taxes, insurance, and *maintenance* will all add up to less than $6,000 per year? Depending on where you are, both taxes and insurance might be more than that.

Second, if you've accounted for those other costs, you should consider occupancy. It is a wonderful stroke of luck, or genius, or marketing, or pricing, if you can maintain 100% occupancy on all properties at all times. The reality for most owners is that some properties will spend some time with no tenants renting them. Why does such a terrible things happen? Well, people get job offers and move. They decide they hate the house. They decide to buy their own house. They get mad and rent from someone else who is willing to answer their phone call about the bathroom sink at 3am. Or whatever.

So, to account for these periods of vacancy, you apply an occupancy rate per unit. Maybe that's 90-something percent, or 80 percent, or in a rough rental market, maybe it's 60%. You need to talk to people who know your area and market conditions, and at least get an idea of what that occupancy rate is now. And understand that it can change due to economic downturn, upturn, government action, etc.

You might be able to get better than average occupancy though! Just understand that that probably means you have a more attractive than average property, or better than average marketing, better service and reputation, lower than average prices, better than average terms, or some combination of those. And some of those things are trade-offs. Lower prices means your maintenance budget or profits might suffer, for example. That in turn might affect service, tenant retention, and ultimately reputation.

Considering these things, are you still willing to buy a property at the razor edge of break-even? If so, maybe you're really speculating on the market, assuming prices will go up for as long as you own it, and it will be liquid enough to get you out of the investment any time you need out. I can't tell you whether that will be the case, and neither can anyone else; but I've known people who were sure it was, and they had to reboot their credit and start their investments over from scratch. The conservative approach is to make the least number of assumptions about market conditions as you reasonably can. When you make offers, they need to account for your risk appetite in that regard.

So what to do if you're dead set on owning rental property, and the numbers aren't working? Well there are a few things.

1. If you're confident in your skills and Ok with certain kinds of risk, you can find properties that you can improve or add value to. You need to be very realistic about these though... people may not pay an extra $1,000 per year, even, for your property just because you put nice paint on it. So a good improvement would be something that results in a discount in the price, which you can fix for less than the discount. Or something that is simply overlooked by previous owners, or unknown to them. For example, if you had experience with easements, zoning, material purchasing and maintenance, or construction techniques that could significantly increase the cashflow of the property.
2. Offer lower, or get better terms. If it's not feasible at the asking price, it's just not. At least, for you. Let someone else get burned by it. Or let someone who has a better advantage for that property make it into a good investment. It doesn't help anyone if you buy it then crash and burn... the bank, you, the tenant, and the neighbors all have a terrible day that way.
3. Put more money down. You mention the mortgage, but that's not the whole story. If you're trying to buy with a low down payment, that means you're financing more. If you can scrape up a larger down payment, that means the mortgage will be less. At some point the down payment is high enough that, at the very least, *some* cash flow is assured. At least, one hopes, assuming taxes, insurance, and maintenance alone do not consume more than you can get for the property. That would be one heck of an "investor special" property.

So, improve it to increase its value to renters, or get it for a lower price, or finance less. Three things you can do to orient an investment toward more reliable cashflow. If you can do some combination of 2 or more of those things, more the better.

Answer (score 2):

Is it risky? Absolutely.

You say it is "very unlikely" that you won't find a tenant. Are you sure of that? Even if that's true today, what will happen to the rental market in 5 years? What if your tenant doesn't pay the rent? I used to own a rental property and I discovered that many don't pay the rent on time or at all when they run short of cash. If the tenant loses his job, or has a major medical expense, or has some absolute necessity that he just really needs to buy, like a new TV, many tenants see paying the rent as optional, something you do when you have spare cash.

What if the place needs repairs? You will have to pay for that, not the tenant. When I owned a rental property, I had one time a water main needed to be replaced, which required digging up the front yard. Cost me $3000. Another time the roof leaked and I had to replace the roof. Etc. You will likely have many goofy service calls. Like once I had a tenant complained that the windows leaked when it rained. I paid a handyman to check it out. He told the tenant that you have to close the windows when it's raining.

I don't know where you live, but in most of the US a tenant has all sorts of legal rights. It is very difficult to evict a tenant who doesn't pay rent or damages the property. I had to evict tenants twice and the process took months. And of course once you start the eviction process, they're not going to pay the rent.

Worst case: What if a tenant trashes the place? I had a tenant who did $10,000 worth of damage.

If you see this as a business, every business involves risk. Maybe you're willing to accept the risk. But if you're thinking that the rent from the other unit will just be free, easy, automatic money ... no.

Of course some people get into the landlord business and make a lot of money at it and love doing it. Personally I found I was not very good at it and I lost money every year. Every. Single. Year.

There's also the question of whether a bank would even approve a loan when you can't afford it without the rental income. But that's another story.